# Mistakenly deleted .cs file content

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've commited a quite bad mistake re-writing and then saving a crucial .cs file.

Pressed CTRL+A (select all), pasted the new content and that's it. My bad. (of course, I thought it was CheckX.aspx.cs when it really was Check.aspx.cs)
Gonna pay more attention to names and re-think the way I name files, but as of now I'd like to know if there's any way I can retrieve all the .cs that I've deleted.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ctrl+Z.  Aside from this, [SCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) and [backup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backup).

Comment: Seems like a good read. Thanks.

Comment: It might be worth your while to investigate intermediate files... you can always decompile to IL if you have a particular module's binaries. But it's not really going to help you if you need to modify the code.  Take a look at Mercurial. It's a wonderful source control tool.

Comment: In addition to Ctrl+Z, you could also close the file and select "No" when asked to save changes.